# Returning nodes in a graph which do not have a rdf:type of rdfs:Class or rdf:Property

Tags: sparql, rdf, json-ld, turtle-rdf

I am using the json-ld format.

Let say I have the following Data Graph

```
{
    "@context": {        
        "rdf": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#",
        "rdfs": "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#",
        "xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#",
        "hr": "http://learningsparql.com/ns/humanResources#",
        "d": "http://learningsparql.com/ns/data#",
        "sh": "http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#"
    },
    "@graph": [
        {
            "@id": "hr:Employee",
            "@type": "rdfs:Class",
            "rdfs:comment": "a good employee",
            "rdfs:label": "model"
        },
        {
            "@id": "hr:Another",
            "@type": "rdfs:Class"
        },
        {
            "@id": "hr:name",
            "@type": "rdf:Property"
        },
        {
            "@id": "hr:randomtype",
            "@type": "hr:invalidtype",
            "rdfs:comment": "some comment about randomtype",
            "rdfs:label": "some label about randomtype"
        },        
        {
            "@id": "hr:typo",
            "@type": "rdfs:Classs",
            "rdfs:comment": "some comment about typo",
            "rdfs:label": "some label about typo"
        },        
        {
            "@id": "hr:missing",
            "rdfs:comment": "some comment about missing"           
        }
    ]
}
```

(ttl equivalent)

```
@prefix d: <http://learningsparql.com/ns/data#> .
@prefix hr: <http://learningsparql.com/ns/humanResources#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

hr:Another a rdfs:Class .

hr:Employee a rdfs:Class ;
    rdfs:label "model" ;
    rdfs:comment "a good employee" .

hr:missing rdfs:comment "some comment about missing" .

hr:name a rdf:Property .

hr:randomtype a hr:invalidtype ;
    rdfs:label "some label about randomtype" ;
    rdfs:comment "some comment about randomtype" .

hr:typo a rdfs:Classs ;
    rdfs:label "some label about typo" ;
    rdfs:comment "some comment about typo" .
```

I would like returned to me the nodes:

```
        {
            "@id": "hr:randomtype",
            "@type": "hr:invalidtype",
            "rdfs:comment": "some comment about randomtype",
            "rdfs:label": "some label about randomtype"
        }
and
        {
            "@id": "hr:typo",
            "@type": "rdfs:Classs",
            "rdfs:comment": "some comment about typo",
            "rdfs:label": "some label about typo"
        }
and
        {
            "@id": "hr:missing",
            "rdfs:comment": "some comment about missing"           
        }
```

because in one case the type is invalid, another has a typo, and the last is missing the type information.

If only the "@id" information was returned, that would be sufficient.

What is the SPARQL query that returns this information?

Comment: See the title of the question: Returning nodes in a graph which do not have a rdf:type of rdfs:Class or rdf:Property. Your select statement does not return the requested information.

Comment: The three nodes I want returned do not have a rdf:type of rdfs:Class or rdf:Property.

Comment: That said, what's the purpose behind those "constraints"? I call it as such because last time you used SHACL. Just checking for schema entities without particular information?

Comment: If the type is not Class or Property it is wrong -- perhaps it is wrong because it is a typo or because it is some other type. SHACL has no ability to validate what I need to be validated.

Comment: @UninformedUser Please see the answer. It provides the information I am looking for...the subject of the three nodes which do not have a type of Class or Property.

Comment: @UninformedUser If you are aware of a way to have SHACL issue validation errors for typo, randomtype, and missing, I and others would be interested.

Comment: wow, sarcasm ... thank you, not that I've shown you the same query last time ... I'm uniformed and sometimes even dumb as my name indicates. ok whatever ... not sure what you want from me now, but with SPARQL it's also not possible, it's a plain query language for RDF - if I ever stated something different, fair enough ... that's why I was asking because you've shown an expected result of triples including the type of error. Anyways, good luck with your project - I'm out of the discussion

Comment: @UninformedUser It is possible with SPARQL. The answer demonstrates that. Your select statement does not and did not return the results I want and therefore is not the answer. It was close and a good try. I am confused about what you do not understand about the question.

Comment: @UninformedUser To repeat what your previous broken suggestion was as it does demonstrate a feature others might be useful in a different context, ```SELECT * 
{ 
    VALUES ?cls {rdfs:Class rdf:Property} 
    ?s ?p ?o 
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {?s a ?cls} 
}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want back all resources that do not have a type of either `rdfs:Class` or `rdf:Property`, then the query could be something like:

```
SELECT ?s
WHERE { 
     ?s ?p ?o .
     FILTER NOT EXISTS { 
             ?s a ?c .
             FILTER(?c IN (rdfs:Class, rdf:Property))
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That is the query I am looking for...or at least it is very close. It can be improved by doing ```SELECT DISTINCT ?s ...``` because one just needs the subject with the incorrect type once and the query as written will return the typo subject three times, for example.

Comment: There may be additional useful information https://www.reddit.com/r/semanticweb/comments/fw4op0/sparql_returning_nodes_in_a_graph_which_do_not/